# Converting JSON to C# classes

Tags: json, dictionary

I am trying to convert the following JSON to c# classes and I am having problems deserializing it.

[image: Error]

```
{
  "base": "NZD",
  "end_date": "2022-08-23",
  "rates": {
    "2021-08-23": {
      "AUD": 0.956173,
      "EUR": 0.586928,
      "GBP": 0.502258,
      "USD": 0.6893
    },
    "2021-08-24": {
      "AUD": 0.956925,
      "EUR": 0.590177,
      "GBP": 0.50541,
      "USD": 0.693675
    },
   "2022-08-23": {
      "AUD": 0.898189,
      "EUR": 0.621674,
      "GBP": 0.525184,
      "USD": 0.616468
    }
  },
  "start_date": "2021-08-23",
  "success": true,
  "timeseries": true
}
```

The rates I would like as a dictionary and I would also like the "AUD", "EUR", "GBP" and "USD" as a dictionary.

I have tried a few tools that I normally use like QuickType.IO but it converts the rates to

```
        [JsonProperty("rates")]
        public Dictionary<string, Rate> Rates { get; set; }


public partial class Rate
    {
        [JsonProperty("AUD")]
        public double Aud { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("EUR")]
        public double Eur { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("GBP")]
        public double Gbp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("USD")]
        public double Usd { get; set; }
    }
```

From my understanding it should probably be more like

```
        [JsonProperty("rates")]
        public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> Rates { get; set; }
```

But none of these will deserialize the JSON.

I would like to use the NewtonSoft JsonConvert.DeseriableObject<> to convert the JSON text to objects.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I can parse that above JSON into the classes you've shown us using Newtonsoft. Show us the actual deserialization, please.

Comment: Or better yet, provide a minimal example that we can copy & paste and execute.

Answer (score -1):

My fault - I was deserializing using the wrong class - I was sure I checked that.

Da.

Sorry for the trouble...